# Read XML file in PySpark with UTF-16LE encoding

Tags: xml, apache-spark, utf-16

I'm running HDInsight Spark cluster on MS Azure cloud.
Spark version is 2.4.6, Scala version is 2.11.12 and Python version is 2.7.12

I have a lot of XML files on an Azure Data Lake Storage, they are encoded with utf-16le (if I run the file -i command) or UCS-2 LE BOM (if I look at the file with Notepad++)

I want to read those files inside a Jupyter notebook to be able to parse the XML and provide some visualization, however, I can't get data to show properly. Here's what I tried so far:

```
%%configure -f
{"conf":{"spark.jars.packages":"com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.10.0"}}

data = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rootTag", "rootElement").option("rowTag", "rowElement").\
option("encoding", "utf-16LE").\
option("charset", "utf-16LE").\
load("abfs://blob@datalakestorage.dfs.core.windows.net/files/")
```

I've tried variations of UTF-16LE writing (utf-16 le, utf-16le, UTF-16LE) but nothing seems to work because when I load the file like this, I either get the empty dataframe:

```
data.show()


root
++
||
++
++
```

or the dataframe loads only the _corrupted_record with Chinese records (the text in this particular file is in German and English):

```
root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|_corrupt_record                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|琼⁵牣慥楴湯慤整∽
```

I've also tried to read the files as RDD:

```
file_rdd = spark.read.text("abfs://blob@datalakestorage.dfs.core.windows.net/files/", wholetext=True).rdd
data = file_rdd.collect()
data[0:15]

[Row(value='��<\x00?\x00x\x00m\x00l\x00 \x00v\           .......
```

Last thing I tried is:

```
data = sc.textFile("abfs://blob@datalakestorage.dfs.core.windows.net/files/", use_unicode=False).map(lambda x: x.decode("utf-16le"))
data.collect()[0:15]
```

I also get an error stating that *UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x00 in position 0: truncated data*

If I manually change the encoding in the Notepad++ the data loads and is readable, but for now, it's not an option for me to reencode all files on the data lake.

Thanks